# Prevent img tag on error prompt xss for GET

Tags: javascript, php, html, get, xss

I want to know how to prevent this type of xss, i've been trying for about 4 hours but nothing works.

`"><img+src%3Dx+onerror%3Dprompt('XSS')>`

This is what I use to prevent xss:

```
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$term = strip_tags($term);
```

This is how I print the results:

`echo "<i>Search results for <b>" . strip_tags($term) . "</b> based on the <b>Name</b> of the servers</i><br /><br />";`

Here is my full php code:

```
<?php
$term = strip_tags($_GET['term']);
$keywords = preg_split('#\s+#', $term);
$c = 0;
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
if(strlen($keyword) < 3){
    $c++;
}
}
if($c > 0){
$errors[] = "One of the keywords you entered is too short.";
}
if(strlen($term) < 4){
$errors[] = "Search string too short!";
}
if(empty($errors) !== true){
echo output_errors($errors);
} else {
echo "<i>Search results for <b>" . strip_tags($term) . "</b> based on the <b>Name</b> of the servers</i><br /><br />";

$name_where        = "`name` LIKE '%" . implode("%' OR `name` LIKE '%", $keywords) . "%'";
$query             = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `servers` WHERE {$name_where} AND `disabled` = 0");

?>
```

Comment: What does MySql have to do with XSS?

Comment: How do you execute $term so there is danger? Print the corresponding line of code here.

Comment: Where does that value come from, and what kind of data do you _expect_ that way? If it’s supposed to be text only - then use `htmlspecialchars` and done. If you explicitly _want_ to pass HTML code to be embedded somewhere – then have a hard think about whether that’s actually a good idea or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$term = filter_var($term, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Maybe try someting like this:

```
$term = filter_var($term, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$term = filter_var($term, FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```

Theres a lot of filters with which you can filter like everything out.

The advantage of `filter_var()` is that you can control the behaviour by, for example, stripping or encoding low and high characters.

Here is a list of filters: [Filters](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)

Comment: Did you try out various filters? for example FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS

Comment: I've had good results with this filter anyways: https://gist.github.com/mbijon/1098477 if all the normal PHP filters don't work - its quite the same as symfony's xss filter. Symfony is just a little bit faster. But normally you are able to filter everything out with PHP filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also `filter_input` to get external variables and optionally filter them.

```
<?php

    // FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS filter HTML-escapes special characters
    $term = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    // FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING strips or encodes unwanted characters
    $term = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Not working means differents things : error, empty string, vulnerable output, .. ?

Comment: I mean that the xss still works ...